# Discrete Math - If two natural numbers divide each other, then they are equal

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

I’m not sure how I would go about proving this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **Hint:** Try proving that $a\mid b\implies a\leq b$.  Try doing this by remembering the definition of divisiblity.  Do you remember what that is?

Comment: Please include a full statement of the problem you want help with in the body of the Question, not only in the title.  Take the opportunity to add more context to your Question.  For example, what related material in learning "Discrete Math" do you think this exercise was meant to reinforce?

Answer (score 2):

let $a,b$ two natural numbers, if $$a|b$$ then $b=ma$ and $m$ is a natural number, and if $$b|a$$ then $$a=nb$$ thus we get
$$b=mnb$$ and can be written as $$b-mnb=0$$ and from here we get $$b(1-mn)=0$$ Can you finish?

Comment: I’m sorry, but I don’t know what ‘|’ represents.

Comment: that means is divisible by...

Comment: I see. I can follow the steps up to the last one you posted, but I don’t understand how b(1-mn)=0 leads to b=a.

Comment: @FenrirMistuki In the case that $b\neq 0$ this implies something about $(1-mn)$ (*remember that the only way a product is equal to zero is if one of the terms being multiplied is zero*).  Now that we know something about $1-mn$, we can rearrange this and remember that $m$ and $n$ are integers, which will imply *what* integers they are, and then once we know what $m$ and $n$ are equal to will allow us to see the exact nature of the relationship between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I think I get it now.

Comment: ok i think the Problem is solved now, have a nice evening!